# getting text from second child span with jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to get text from nested span(which is the second of two elements in an `li`) into an input. my function isnt working not sure why.

html

```
<ul id="dir"><li><img><span>TEXT TO GET</span></li></ul>
<input type="text" id="target">
```

jQuery

```
$("#dir li").click(function(){
$("target").val($(this).children[1].text());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or this:

```
$("#dir li").click(function(){
   $("#target").val($($(this).children()[1]).text());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.find()`

```
var text = $(this).find("span").text();
$("target").val(text);
```

Comment: Just note that if there happens to be more than one `span` in the future, you'll need to use the `:first` selector e.g. `var text = $(this).find("span:first").text();`